# Is classical electromagnetism conformally invariant? (and a bit of general covariance)

Tags: electromagnetism, conformal-field-theory, coordinate-systems, covariance, classical-field-theory

The contest is a flat $4d$ Minkowsky space.
A conformal transformation is a diffeomorphism $\tilde x(x)$ such that the metric transforms as
\begin{equation*}
 \tilde g_{\tilde \mu \tilde \nu} = w^2(x) g_{\mu \nu} 
\end{equation*}
This implies that $ \left| det \left( \frac{\partial \tilde x}{\partial x} \right) \right| = |w| $.
Tensors transform as required by the change of coordinate.
The lagrangian is the usual $\mathscr{L}= -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}-A^{\mu}j_{\mu}$.

Now, IF the tranformed action is 
$ \tilde{S}= \int_{\tilde M} \sqrt{|\tilde g| }\tilde{ \mathscr{L}}\, d\tilde x^0 \cdots d\tilde x^4 \, $ $\,$ , I can show, by hand or by principle, that $\tilde S=S$.  <sub>For example because $\mathscr{L}=\tilde{\mathscr{L}}$, and 
$\sqrt{|\tilde g| }$ compensates the change of variables</sub>

> Is it correct?

If that is the case, by doing this I noticed that I never used the fact that the transformation is conformal, and in fact, since the action is an integral of a scalar function, it should be invariant under every general change of coordinates.
 So, for second part of the question, considering conformal transformations as opposed to generic diffeomorphisms for this theory,

> is the significance of conformal transformations linked to the fact that they are a group with a finite number of generators, so that we can obtain a conserved current via Noether's first theorem?

<sub>sorry if this sounds trivial, but at least for the first part I've seen two methods of proving it and neither of those was convincing, so I feared that I might be missing something.</sub>

Comment: The conformal invariance of the Maxwell equations was shown by Bateman. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_symmetry and references therein.